# How I can persist the broadcast variable when the connection is lost in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm having an issue with broadcast variables in pyspark. These broadcast variables are unavailable when the connection is reset or lost, since they are not loosely coupled.

```
def insertItem(rdd):
    db = boto3.resource("Dynamodb")
    deltaTable = db.Table(region.value)

region = sc.broadcast('test')
```

When the connection is lost/reset then i'm getting broadcast variables are not loaded error. So how I can persist the broadcast variable even if in case of any network issues?